# AXIOS in express js return Promise { undefine }

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

i new learn expressjs and axios

i create a folder utils and place the
**axios.js file**

```
const axios = require('axios');


loadDataPesan=async function(opts){
    
    axios.get('localhost/getData', {
        params: {
          opt: opts,
          nis: "123123",
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.datas) // ITS NORMALLY SHOW THE CORRECT DATA 
        return response.data.datas; // HERE MY PROBLEM, WHEN I RETURN IT DATA always Promise { }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        return error; 
      });
}

module.exports = { loadDataPesan };
```

**here my app.js files**

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const { loadContact } = require('./utils/contact');
const { loadDataPesan } = require('./utils/axios');
const app = express();
const port = 8899;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(expressLayout);

// BUILTIN MIDDLEWARE
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    const contacts  = loadContact();
    const dataaxio = loadDataPesan("SUBS","912830123");

    
    console.log(dataaxio); // **HERE MY PROBLEM RESPONSE ALWAYS Promise { }**
    
    res.render('contact', { 
        layout: 'layouts/main-layout',
        title: 'Halaman Contact',
        contact:contacts,
    });
})
```

thanks you in advance if someone can help me

i try given async in function but it same also i try callback response its same also

Comment: you are not returning anything from `loadDataPesan` - and since it's `async` (for no discernible reason since you never `await`) it returns a Promise ... immediately (without waiting for the response to the request) resolving to `undefined` (not `{undefine}` as you claim) ... fix by `return axios .... etc`, and since you're using .then/.catch, don't even bother tagging that function `async` - however, you'll still need to use .then or async await instead of `const dataaxio = loadDataPesan("SUBS","912830123");` ... since your function will still return a Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async/await` to wait for the result. You may need to catch the error.

```
app.get('/contact', async (req, res) => {    <-- convert it to async function
    const contacts  = loadContact();
    const dataaxio = await loadDataPesan("SUBS","912830123");  <-- await for response

    
    console.log(dataaxio); 
    
    res.render('contact', { 
        layout: 'layouts/main-layout',
        title: 'Halaman Contact',
        contact:contacts,
    });
})
```

and return the data from `loadDataPesan` function as

```
loadDataPesan = async function(opts) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('localhost/getData', {
      params: {
        opt: opts,
        nis: "123123",
      }
    });

    console.log(response.data.datas); // Log the correct data
    return response.data.datas; // Return the data

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error; // Throw the error to be caught by the caller
  }
}
```

Comment: ugghh thanks you so much ,, i got it now,, its solved ,, thanks you so much, i try this but still not solved fullly, i want to checklist this helper but i only can check it one,, but thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code.

First you don't `await` for the `loadDataPesan` to return anything.

This means that when

```
console.log(dataaxio);
```

Is called, the promise hasn't resolved yet. Making the function where this is called an `async` function will allow you to add `await` before the call of the function `loadDataPesan`. This will stop the execution of your code until the promise in `loadDataPesan` is resolved

```
 async (req, res) => {
    const contacts  = loadContact();
    const dataaxio = await loadDataPesan("SUBS","912830123");
 // ...
```

Secondly, you don't actually return anything in `loadDataPesan`. You do have a `return` statement in the callback of your promise (the function inside the `then` method), but you don't return the promise at all.

To fix that you just need to add a `return` before the call of `axios`

```
const axios = require('axios');


loadDataPesan=async function(opts){
    return axios.get('localhost/getData', {
        params: {
          opt: opts,
          nis: "123123",
        }
      })
     // ...
}

module.exports = { loadDataPesan };
```

Comment: Did this fully answered your question ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems that I can see ->

1. In the axios.js file, this line

```
loadDataPesan=async function(opts)
```

you are not using the **const** keyword which is recommended. Either write this
way ->

```
const loadDataPesan = async function(opts) {
  // Function body
};
```

or this way ->

```
async function loadDataPesan(opts) {
  // Function body
}
```

2. When exporting a single function, export like this ->

```
module.exports = loadDataPesan;
```

3. As pointed out in other answer, if you are using using async keyword at the top of a function, use **async/await syntax**. It is also a good practice to wrap the code in a **try-catch** block for better error handling. Here is an example of how you can restructure your code, I used the **Router method** of express module for routing. You can learn more about it [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) under the express.Router section.

axios.js file

```
const axios  = require("axios");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.get(
      "a_url_path"
    );
    res.send(resp.data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error.message);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js file ->

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axiosFile = require("./axios");


//other code....

app.use("/data", axiosFile);

// other code...

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 5000");
});
```